# Excel Find Average Between Dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an unpivoted dataset where column A is country, column B are dates (01/01/2020 - 01/01/2021) and column C are number of Covid cases. In a separate tab I have a column A with the individual country names and I want to calculate the average of Covid cases for specific dates (e.g. between 01/01/2020 and 15/01/2020). However, using averageifs I keep getting #DIV/O!. Also, if I do "=IF(B2>1/1/2022,1,0)" where C2 is a date prior to 2021, I still get 1, which is wrong. I think something is wrong with the way dates are formatted but cannot seem to solve it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that `=IF(B2>1/1/2022,1,0)` is not a correct way to evaluate a cell against a date. Do you have some sample data with expected results to show?

Comment: Try `AVERAGEIFS()` like `=AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,"USA",B:B,">="&DATE(2020,1,1),B:B,"<="&DATE(2020,1,15))`

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly for the date but I still get #DIV/0! This is my exact formula: =AVERAGEIFS('Tab 1'!$E:$E,'Tab 1'!$C:$C,'Tab 2'!$B4,'Tab 1'!$D:$D,'Tab 2'!$A4,'Tab 1'!$B:$B,">="&DATE(2020,1,2),'Tab 1'!$B:$B,">="&DATE(2020,1,13))

Comment: In the last part it should say "<=" not ">=", apologies it is a typo in the comment but the formula is correctly written in my excel.